# Draw spheroid in Paraview?

Tags: paraview

Does someone know how to draw spheroid in Paraview?

What have I tried:

1. to make something by using menu "Sources":

   - there is Sphere object which I can't change, in a manner to make it spheroid
   - there is Programmable object, but none of available vtk data types can make spheroid, and the one that assumable can is `vtkParametricEllipsoid`, which is not available
2. read the manual

There is Python console in Paraview, so maybe someone knows more about it

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone cares...

It was much easier then I assumed.
At the top of properties panel, to the right, there is small "gear" button, that can toggle advanced object properties. After creating sphere, roll this advanced properties and use Scale input boxes to define X, Y, Z radiuses.